# show default time when user loads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

i want to show default time when user loads the page in hours and minutes dropdown box. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/34/.
Below is the code to create textbox to display hours and minutes:

```
<input id="timeHours" name="timeHours" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-id="dojoSelHours" value="10" />&nbsp;:
<font size="1">Minutes</font>

<input id="timeMins" name="timeMins" maxlength="3" style="width:50px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: {timePattern: 'mm', clickableIncrement: 'T02:05:00',visibleIncrement: 'T02:00:00' }" data-dojo-id="dojoSelMins" value="05" />
```

In hours drop down i want to show "10" and in  minutes drop down i want to display "05" when user loads the page. **I should not use hidden variables to achieve this**. I achieved this using hidden variables but i should not use hidden variables.Please suggest.

Below is the JS code:

```
    ready(function () {
        // Set the current time when starting up
        var time = registry.byId("timeHours");
        time.set({
            "constraints": {
                timePattern: 'HH',
                clickableIncrement: 'T01:00:00',
                visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00',
                visibleRange: 'T24:00:00'
            } 
            //"value": document.getElementsByName('timeHours')[0].value
        });

        //Minutes
        var timeM = registry.byId("timeMins");

    });

});
```

--EDIT--

Please find the http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/37/ , shows default values using hidden variables. But i want to show default values without using hidden variables.

Comment: can you also post a fiddle using "hidden variables" ?

Comment: @Teo - http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/37/ , shows default values using hidden variables.

Comment: is this it ? http://jsfiddle.net/r2L7k6pw/

Comment: @Teo, i'm sorry for being unclear.  I want to show 10:05 i.e., 10 in hours drop down and 05 in minutes dropdown always whenever page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I deleted my previous answer which generated a rounded hour and minute based on the current time. Now that you've clarified that you want to *always* default to 10:05, and seeing how dojo's `TimeTextBox` works it seems that you need to give a proper "Time" string. See the example below and [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8o23tbLu/38/).

```
var time = registry.byId("timeHours");
time.set({
    "constraints": {
        timePattern: 'HH',
        clickableIncrement: 'T01:00:00',
        visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00',
        visibleRange: 'T24:00:00'
    },
    "value": 'T10:05:00'
});

//Minutes
var timeM = registry.byId("timeMins");
timeM.set({
    "value": 'T10:05:00'
});
```